# Microsoft убрала дистрибутив Visual Basic 6.0?

Tags: visual-basic

Надо отредактировать 1 программку, написанную на vb 6.0. В инете ссылки на торрент-трекеры и software-сайты, на сайте [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/vbrun/default.aspx) не нашел ссылки. Неужели они забросили vb 6.0 и убрали скачку дистрибутива? На работе, к сожалению, трекеры и другие software-сайты блокируются, поэтому вся надежда на офф сайт MS.

Comment: 1998-го года? Я бы не удивлялся.

Comment: @D-side да, он прошлого века. Такая вот задача - окунуться в прошлое)

Comment: Он прошлого **тысячелетия**. Может быть проще портировать на свежие версии VB.NET, заодно и совместимость со свежими системами будет понадёжнее.

Comment: @D-side так по идее сначала надо открыть его в vb6, нет?

Comment: @Denis, майкрософт предлагает [мигрировать проекты с VB6 на .NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dd408373.aspx)

Comment: Файлы с исходным кодом просто текстовые, их можно открывать хоть в Блокноте.

Comment: Ув-мый Denis, просьба, например, [**здесь**](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39553/) пояснить причины отклонения [**данной**](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/80088) правки. Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных добрый день. Правка была отклонена по причине отсутствия картинок в конечном результате, которые были изначально залиты ТС-ом.

Comment: Denis, полагаю, что они в вопросе излишни, что я и указал в комментарии к правке. Автора вопроса интересовали общие принципы поиска хостинга/сервера/движка для своего сайта на JS/CSS/HTML, а как выглядят блоки, особой роли не играет.

Comment: @СашаЧерных значит мы с вами недопоняли друг друга, потому что вы оставили ссылки на картинки в посте, но при этом убрали их вставку.

Comment: Denis, да, извиняюсь, забыл убрать ссылки снизу. Если удалю их, есть другие причины для отклонения правки?

Comment: @СашаЧерных нет, все остальное в норме! да и я был невнимательным и можно было улучшить правку, удалив ссылки)

Comment: Внёс правку [**ещё раз**](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/80102). Благодарю за доброжелательный конструктивный тон.

Comment: @СашаЧерных одобрено!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На официальном сайте в публичном доступе дистрибутива нет. Однако по подписке DreamSpark я его отлично вижу и могу скачать (см. скрин):

[image: Скачивание visual basic 6]

Если Вы - студент, преподаватель или сотрудник вуза, то Вы можете скачать Visual Basic 6.0 через Microsoft DreamSpark, либо по другой легальной подписке Microsoft.

Comment: В этом году закончил, подписка была. Проверю, осталась или нет. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Полагаю, что да. Они и куда более новые версии убрали с сайта.

По нему даже справку найти проблематично, хотя её они не убрали.